# localStorage is not updating edited information

Tags: javascript

I have problem editing local storage data. I saved  Array of Array-list in local storage and it works, or save. However, when i tried to edit, it only edit temporarily and the edited data disappear when i refresh the page  and  it shows the original data i saved

```
function editinfo(){
    var name = document.getElementById("nameB").value; 
    var price = document.getElementById("priceB").value;
    var quant = document.getElementById("quantityB").value;
    var retrieved = window.localStorage.getItem("done");
    var pro = JSON.parse(retrieved);
    for (i = 0; i < pro.length; ++i){
         if(pro[i][0] === name){ 
            pro[i][1]=  price
            pro[i][2] = quant; 
         } else{
            console.log("There is no such data to edit"); 
         }
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem("done", JSON.stringify(pro));  
}
```

// I saved information on local storage, I read data from server.
var bevInventory = $.getJSON('http://pub.jamaica-inn.net/fpdb/api.php?username=jorass&password=jorass&action=inventory_get');

```
function Info(){
    var info = []; 
    bevInventory.done(function(result){
        for(i = 0; i < result.payload.length; ++i){
         if(result.payload[i].namn != ""){
         var makeList = [result.payload[i].namn, result.payload[i].price, result.payload[i].count];
         info.push(makeList);
         }
        }
        var xx =  window.localStorage.setItem("done", JSON.stringify(info)); 
    })

    return info; 
}
```

Comment: Its most likely a typo. Show us how you save, how you retrieve the data, and fix editInfo() as currently its not properly formatted

Comment: Are you sure that your code runs till the `localStorage.setItem()`? Do you have any errors in your console? What `pro` returns?

Comment: @lonut , i don't have  error in  console. Actually i can print out the local storage content

Comment: Maybe you clear the local storage somewhere using `localStorage.clear()`?

Comment: Update your question with the code and explain. Do not add it as a comment.

Comment: When do you call your function?

Comment: maybe `Info()` is being called after `editinfo()` or `Info()` is returning after `editInfo()` is called?

Comment: @lonut i call the function after info function, storing in localstorge and then retrieve, parse . the function return from info is Array of array size 3                 [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ....]

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails if there is no "done" data initially in localStorage. JSON.parse() parses null (because of no data) and then error occurs on line

```
pro.length
```

So it's better to check if it's a first launch and there is no data:

```
if (!pro) {
    pro = [];
}
```

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3o4mbg4v/8/)

After first executing of editinfo() data successfully saves in localStorage.

Comment: yes it save the edited information, the problem is when i refresh the page the local storage change back to the original data

Comment: Can you provide more details about the problem? I tried your Info() code and it works well, "done" data stores in localStorage - http://jsfiddle.net/ze5obkno/1/

Comment: I am using html5 form to get input from user and change the content of local storage. When i insert the input and refresh the page the local storage changed and the edited data display on table format, however, if i refresh again the page, the local storage back to the original data. Edit does not change the local storage data permanently. I want the data changed permanently not  temporarily

Comment: Here you are a working example of reading and writing user input to localStorage - https://jsfiddle.net/avadon/3o4mbg4v/13/. It works fine, so that means that you have to log your every writing to storage in order to find a line where you resetting localStorage or writing corrupted data (which also leads to resetting).

Comment: the problem was refreshing the  page overwrite the local Storage. I am reading the file from server and save on local storage. When , the page refresh it send request to server and overwrite on local storage. I deactivate the request and it works now without problem

Comment: So that means that the problem is with your request. As I told you previously, you have to log your data (console.log(data)) in order to detect the line where you write empty data instead of correct one. Because localStorage won't reset your data until you tell it. You can user "debugger;" command to execute code line by line and monitoring localStorage at the same time.

Comment: If that's not enough and you can't handle the problem then provide a full example of your code (not just parts). Then I will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to check first, and add data to local storage if it does not exist.  Like this

```
function editinfo() {
    var name = 'bob';
    var price = 1;
    var quant = 2; // loaded dynamically from page.

    if (window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty("done")) {
        var retrieved = window.localStorage.getItem("done");
        var pro = JSON.parse(retrieved);
        for(i = 0; i < pro.length; ++i){
            if(pro[i][0] === name){ 
               pro[i][1] =  price
               pro[i][2] = quant; 
            }
        }
    } else {
        pro = [[name, price, quant]];
    } 
    window.localStorage.setItem("done", JSON.stringify(pro));  
}
```

Comment: the problem is still persist

Comment: @user3262564 you need to make sure your promise (bevInventory) finishes before you let the user make changes.  So if editInfo is a callback from a button click, make the button unclickable until bevInventory is done.  Adding a console log to it, will help debug this.